# which one of these paths has the priority: /usr or /usr/local

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path

I want to install `aria2c` manually by copying it to `/usr/local/bin` since I installed aria2c with apt on `/usr/bin`

which one of those is going to be executed if I type `aria2c`?

Comment: note that copying executables into places is usually a bad idea – they typically want a specific version of the libraries they're using (namely, one that is ABI-compatible with what they were built with). In fact, I'd wager that "I want to install ... by copying it to /usr/local/bin" comes with more "nope, won't work" than you think. What's the reason you're doing this, instead of, say, using the installation tool from the source code build?

Comment: Concur that this is a really bad idea, and if you have to ask this question then you really shouldn't be doing it in the first place.

Answer (score 23):

The executable that will be executed depends on the ordering of the directories in the `PATH` variable.

If `/usr/bin` is listed before `/usr/local/bin`, then `/usr/bin/aria2c` would be executed rather than `/usr/local/bin/aria2c`.

If your shell does hashing of executables, and if it has already accessed `aria2c` from `/usr/bin` before you installed the same utility in `/usr/local/bin`, then it may choose `/usr/bin/aria2c` regardless of the ordering of the directories in `PATH`.  Note that this probably only happens in the specific case where you have used the utility, then install it in another location, and then try to use it again in the same shell session. The command `hash -r` would clear the remembered locations of utilities in a shell session. See also [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609)

If you have an alias or shell function called `aria2c`, then that would be used before the shell uses `PATH` to locate the executable.

---

On my personal (non-Linux) system:

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/X11R6/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/games
```

As you can see, `/usr/local/bin` is way after `/usr/bin` on my system. I've set it up like that to *avoid* accidentally overriding base system utilities in `/usr/bin`.  You likely want the opposite order if you want to give local executables priority over the ones in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: +1 specifically for calling out `hash -r`!

Answer (score 4):

It's weird I cannot find an answer on this SE website.

It depends on your shell but generally there's the `PATH` environment variable which contains directories the shell is checking in order to execute a command. Those directories are separated with a semicolon `:`.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/wine/bin:/home/birdie/bin
```

Binaries are being searched for from left to right, i.e. in my example if I have the same binary in `/usr/local/bin` and `/bin` the binary from `/usr/local/bin` will take precedence.

In the meantime if your shell has aliases, functions support those will be executed first in case they are defined. You can see them by running `alias` and `set`. And there's yet another category `built-in` commands. So the order is:

- aliases
- functions
- built-in commands
- binaries found in `$PATH` which is looked up from left to right

Lastly, worth noting and remembering: aliases do **not** work (not defined) in shell scripts.

Comment: Not exactly what the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45578/why-do-so-many-programs-live-in-path/45579#45579) asked but the answer to this post also answers this OP's question.

Comment: Aliases aren't defined (don't work) because your `$HOME/.bashrc` checks `$-` and exits early if it doesn't contain `i` (interactive). Read `man bash`, the `INVOCATION` section.

Comment: @waltinator I'm not sue whose shell init files you're talking about or why you mention `bash` specifically, but you will notice that aliases are not substituted in non-interactive shells even if they are defined. It has very little to do with your `.bashrc` checking `$-`.

Answer (score 0):

More simple solution is to use `which` to see the program that would be executed.

Manpage ...

> it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have
> been executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt.

example:

```
[~] echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/lib/llvm/13/bin:/usr/lib/llvm/12/bin
[~] echo '#!/bin/bash' > hello_world.sh
[~] echo 'echo "Hello World"' >> hello_world.sh
[~] chmod 755 hello_world.sh 
[~] sudo cp hello_world.sh /bin/
[~] sudo cp hello_world.sh /usr/bin/
[~] sudo cp hello_world.sh /usr/local/bin/
[~] which hello_world.sh
/usr/local/bin/hello_world.sh
```

**Addition**

It brought to my attention that `hash` can alter the way commands are executed from. But in most cases the programs aren't hashed cause of a little performance boost. My hash list has only two commands in it, all the time.

```
[~] hash
hits    command
   3    /usr/bin/man
   1    /bin/bash
```

As long you don't hash your commands the `which` command should be fine. Or you use `type -p hello_world.sh` instead. The `type` command is part of the `bash` like `hash` is. And I assume they will communicate with each other in some way.

To be save you can call the `hash` command without any arguments to see all the hashed programs.

Comment: The `which` command cannot tell you which command will be executed, because it does not know about the shell's hash table.

Comment: that's new to me and there is nothing in the manpage about some hash tables. This command is designed to do one thing and that doesn't work ?.. can you give me an example

Comment: Read `bash -c 'help hash'`, and compare with `type which`, you can trivially reproduce this by hashing a `$PATH` lookup and then removing the file it points to. `which` is an external binary and thus cannot know what the shell has already hashed and may choose use, which may not simply be whatever is first in `$PATH`. Instead of `which`, either use `type -p`, or `command -v`. `which` is a broken hand-me-down from `csh` and should not be used.

Comment: thx for the advice. I added/considered this in my post.